# How do I get SymPy to collect partial derivatives?

Tags: python, sympy, partial, derivative, collect

I have been using SymPy to expand the terms of a complex partial differential equation and would like to use the collect function to gather terms. However, it seems to have a problem dealing with second (or higher order) derivatives where the variables of differentiation differ.

In the code example below `collect(expr6...` works, but `collect(expr7 ...` does not, returning the error message `"NotImplementedError: Improve MV Derivative support in collect"`. The error is clearly related to the `psi.diff(x,y)` difference in the two cases. Is it obvious to anyone what I need to do to have `collect(expr7 ...` work?

cheers

Richard

Example:

```py
from sympy import *

psi = Function("psi") (x,y,z,t)

expr6=2*psi.diff(x,x)+3*U*psi.diff(x)+5*psi.diff(y)
expr7=2*psi.diff(x,y)+3*U*psi.diff(x)+5*psi.diff(y)

collect(expr6, psi.diff(x),evaluate=False, exact=False)  # works
#collect(expr7, psi.diff(x),evaluate=False, exact=False)
   # throws an error: NotImplementedError: Improve MV Derivative support in collect
```

Answer (score 0):

I've bumped into this issue and my workaround is to perform a substitution with simple dummy variables first, `collect` based on these simple variables, and then substitute back the more advanced variables. There might be some corner cases, but it seems to work for me.

```py
from sympy import symarray, collect
def mycollect(expr, var_list, evaluate=True, **kwargs):
    """ Acts as collect but substitute the symbols with dummy symbols first so that it can work with partial derivatives. 
        Matrix expressions are also supported. 
    """
    if not hasattr(var_list, '__len__'):
        var_list=[var_list]
    # Mapping Var -> Dummy, and Dummy-> Var
    Dummies=symarray('DUM', len(var_list))
    Var2Dummy=[(var, Dummies[i]) for i,var in enumerate(var_list)]
    Dummy2Var=[(b,a) for a,b in Var2Dummy]
    # Replace var with dummies and apply collect
    expr = expr.expand().doit()
    expr = expr.subs(Var2Dummy)
    if hasattr(expr, '__len__'):
        expr = expr.applyfunc(lambda ij: collect(ij, Dummies, **kwargs))
    else:
        expr = collect(expr, Dummies, evaluate=evaluate, **kwargs)
    # Substitute back
    if evaluate:
        return expr.subs(Dummy2Var)
    d={}
    for k,v in expr.items():
        k=k.subs(Dummy2Var)
        v=v.subs(Dummy2Var)
        d[k]=v
    return d
```

For your example:

```py
mycollect(expr6, psi.diff(x), evaluate=False)
mycollect(expr7, psi.diff(x), evaluate=False)
```

returns:

```
{Derivative(psi(x, y, z, t), (x, 2)): 2, Derivative(psi(x, y, z, t), x): 3*U, 1: 5*Derivative(psi(x, y, z, t), y)}
{Derivative(psi(x, y, z, t), x, y): 2, Derivative(psi(x, y, z, t), x): 3*U, 1: 5*Derivative(psi(x, y, z, t), y)}
```