# Sympy trouble with simplifying partial derivatives

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I do the following to generate an expression in Sympy:

1. Create some matrix Q_{ij} which holds some functions \eta, \mu, \nu, of x and y.
2. Sum over indices and take some partial derivatives.
3. Substitute some simple expressions for \eta, \mu, and \nu (say \sin(x)*\cos(y)).
4. Try to simplify the expression so that it explicitly calculates the partial derivatives of the simple expressions.

When I do this, it gives me the following error:
`NotImplementedError: Improve MV Derivative support in collect`

The specific code that I used is:

```
from sympy import *

# Set up system and generate functions
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
i, j, k, m, p = symbols('i j k m p')
xi = Matrix([x, y, z])
lims = range(0, 3)

eta = Function('eta', real=True)(x, y)
mu = Function('mu', real=True)(x, y)
nu = Function('nu', real=True)(x, y)

Q = Matrix([[2/sqrt(3)*eta, nu, 0],
            [nu, -1/sqrt(3)*eta + mu, 0],
            [0, 0, -1/sqrt(3)*eta - mu]])

# Create complicated expression of partial derivatives
Phi_L1 = -sum(Eijk(3, p + 1, i + 1)
              *diff(diff(diff(Q[k, l], xi[j]), xi[j]), xi[p])
              *diff(Q[k, l], xi[i])
              for i in lims
              for j in lims
              for k in lims
              for l in lims
              for p in lims
              )

Phi_L1 = simplify(Phi_L1)

# Choose example functions and try to evaluate expression explicitly
eta1 = sin(x)*cos(y)
mu1 = sinh(x)*cosh(y)
nu1 = x**2*y**2
expr1 = Phi_L1.subs(eta, eta1).subs(mu, mu1).subs(nu, nu1)
simplify(expr1)
```

I couldn't find a simpler example that gives the same error. For example, the following works as intended:

```
f = Function('f', real=True)(x, y)
expr = diff(diff(f, x), y)
simplify(expr.subs(f, sinh(x)*cosh(y)))
```

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/20492

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'collect' and 'simplify' have known problems with higher order partial derivatives  https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/9068  outlines the issue

The example shown is

```
import sympy as sp
x, y = sp.symbols("x y")
f, g = sp.symbols("f g", cls=sp.Function, args=(x,y))
f, g = f(), g()

expr1 = g.diff(x, 2) + f.diff(x, 2) + 5*f.diff(x, 2) + 2*f.diff(x) + 9*f.diff(x)
expr2 = g.diff(x, 2) + f.diff(x, 2) + 5*f.diff(x, 2) + 2*f.diff(x) + 9*f.diff(x) + g.diff(x).diff(y) + f.diff(x).diff(y)
```

which works correctly and show the expected output for both expr1 and expo2

`sp.collect(expr1, f)` works wonderfully but `sp.collect(expr2, f)` fails with the known error as the implementation is not finished...

Comment: Not to my knowledge, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58700443/how-do-i-get-sympy-to-collect-partial-derivatives had the same sort of problem so you could ask them?

Answer (score 0):

This does not address the error (which is apparently a bug), but one work around for the case of explicitly taking derivatives of simple functions is to just use the `doit()` function. In this case, that would look like (following the code posted in the question):

`simplify(expr1.doit())`